# How can I display the Label from class

Tags: twig, pimcore

the title says all. 
It is certainly so easy and yet it does not succeed.

```
{% set myObject = pimcore_object(2369) %}
{{ myObject.getArtikelName() }}
```

Now I want to display the Label from ArtikelName but I cant find it.

Comment: unclear, what do you mean with `label`?

Comment: Label is store in class definition. You can use field "key" and translate it like: {{ YourFieldKey|trans }}. Method getObjectVars() return you all keys

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{% set object = pimcore_object(objectID) %}
{{ object.getClass().getFieldDefinition('itemCode[your_field_name_key]').getTitle() }}
```

Comment: Woow thx it works.  I would not have expacted with such a long syntax. Know I understand it a litle better. °!° Thank you verry much!